# Angular materials tree - how to have some checkboxes exclusive with each other and others can be checked simultaneously

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am following [this](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples) to get tree based dropdowns with checkboxes in my app. My code uses the code from example 1 to build the checkbox trees, the only difference being the data.

I want to have it so that for **some** of the data, only one checkbox option can be selected (meaning the other choices are deselected when checked) and other data allows as many checkboxes as the user wants. In the demo material from the above it allows as many checks as you want, and my current implementation works in the same way.

For example see the following data:

```
const TREE_DATA = {
    Groceries: {
      'Almond Meal flour': null,
      'Organic eggs': null,
      'Protein Powder': null,
      'Fruits' : {
         'Apple' : null,
         'Berries' : null,
         'Orange' : null,
         'Quantity:' :{
            '10 grams' : null,
            '20 grams' : null,
            '30 grams' : null,
         },
      },
    },
    Other : {
       'Lawnmower' : null,
       'Demister' : null,
       'Trowel' : null,
 };
```

From this example, if I wanted only the data under "Quantity" to use radio buttons (meaning only 1 can be checked at a time) but the rest of the data used checkboxes that allowed for multiple selection, how could I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Just use a mutually exclusive mat-radio-group and bind a ng-model to it. Then apply those via type or similar to only certain tree-nodes where desired..

Comment: @iLuvLogix how to I go about applying them to certain tree nodes?

Comment: That depends on the desired logic and the tree-data - can you edit your question to include more details and explain on which condition you want to have the mutually exclusive checkboxes?

Comment: @iLuvLogix changed the question. My HTML and typescript matches the example code from the link provided

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I'll write you an answer, give me a sec or two..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the
mat-tree-node
element I added both a mat-checkbox and mat-radio-button, with each of these containing a if statement
*ngIf="isQuantityOption(node)"
where isQuantityOption where works as such

```
isQuantityOption(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean{
  return (this.getParentNode(node)?.item == 'Quantity:');
}
```

This means that for each node in my array it is check whether the parent node is "Quantity:". If so, it creates a radio button rather than a checkbox